# Do any current (early 2012) Macs support Intel's Smart Response Technology (SRT)

Tags: ssd, macos

Intel's SRT uses a small SSD (up to 64 GB) as a cache for the hard disk. Or just the first 64 GB of a larger SSD. Per this [Intel document](http://download.intel.com/support/chipsets/sb/intel_smart_response_technology_user_guide.pdf) this needs a Z68 Express board and Windows Vista or 7. Various sources say the 2011 iMacs use the Z68 chipset.

Is this supported, or an equivalent feature, on any current Mac? If so, where can I read more?

Comment: Compare to the "Fusion Drive" on some Macs ... ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no current implementation of this technology in the current iMac with the requisite Z68 chipset, or any other Mac. I'm not even sure that any other Macs from this (last?) year have the Z68 chipset!

Comment: Any idea if this has changed with the newest round of Ivy Bridge laptops?

Comment: @matthias no I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by GEdgar, the "Fusion Drive" is a similar feature. However it is a software solution, from what I read

Comment: Fusion differs in that the SSD part is additional space that is used in conjunction with the main HD.  a 1TB normal drive and a 120Gb SSD will give you 1120Gb of usable space.  Under SRT the SSD is invisible and merely caches copies of the data.  Another point to note is that a normal SSD is fine with Fusion, but with SRT you really need one made from SLC chips, not MLC (the majority of drives) because there is a much shorter write lifecycle on SSD drives compared to magnetic ones, and caching onto an MLC drive is going to kill it fast.  This is why a lot of 'cache' SSDs overprovision by 100%